# Can't display .swf files on a page with httpHandler

Tags: object, video, flash, handler

Read the last EDIT, please.

I have a page in which I should display some media data.
For this I'm using html  tag, like this:

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" width="320" height="240">
    <param name="src" value="some_media_url" />
    <param name="AutoSize" value="true">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="false">
    <param name="StretchToFit" value="true">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
</object>
```

In my case, I should get media data from SQL server by some MediaHandler.ashx http handler. 
When I get an audio(.mp3, .wma) or video(.flv, .mp4) stream this works fine.
But I'm getting some problems with .swf flash files.
For this type of files I change `<object> type` to be "application/x-shockwave-flash". In this case when I use some remote path, like http://www.tizag.com/pics/example.swf, it works fine:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="240">
    <param name="src" value='http://www.tizag.com/pics/example.swf' />
    <param name="AutoSize" value="true">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="false">
    <param name="StretchToFit" value="true">
</object>
```

But, it doesn't work with my handler. It neither works with local paths,like "c:\videos\example.swf"

Any idea?

EDIT: Actually src for media looks like this:

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" width="320" height="240">
    <param name="src" value="http://localhost:11111/MediaHandler.ashx?Id=1111" />
    <param name="AutoSize" value="true">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="false">
    <param name="StretchToFit" value="true">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
</object>
```

**EDIT:**

This works fine, if I directly refer to an existing file:

```
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="240">
        <param name="src" value="/videos/ETFflash1016.swf" />
        <param name="AutoSize" value="true">
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
        <param name="AutoStart" value="true">
        <param name="StretchToFit" value="true">
    </object>
```

But when I use httpHandler to get file from DB:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="240">       
    <param name="src" value="http://localhost:57031/MediaHandler.ashx?Id=512429" />
    <param name="AutoSize" value="true">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="true">
    <param name="StretchToFit" value="true">
</object>
```

flash is not displayed.

I've compared the output html for these cases, they're the same in both cases (except src param value). Fiddler shows the same result for both requests for .swf file and the browser shows(e.g. in IE dev tool's Netwok tab) that the file was downloaded to client in both cases.
BUT in the case with the handler, flash is not being displayed.

Comment: If the swf is in the localhost, why are you using absolute locations instead of simple relative ones? the sole "folder/file.swf" should work. If you can't see it check the permissions of the file itself. And it will be useful if you let us know about how to reach the file over the net in order to run a test in jsfiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Fiddler shows the same result for both requests for .swf file

In Fiddler, Response Headers, do both the local file and ASHX handler return the same `Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash` ?

Comment: Yes, and not only "Content-Type", but all Response Headers parameters are the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="file.swf" style="width:640px;height:480px;margin:10px 36px;">
<param name="movie" value="file.swf" />
<param name="AutoSize" value="true">
<param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
<param name="AutoStart" value="false">
<param name="StretchToFit" value="true">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
</object>
```

it worked for me

Comment: thanks for reply. Your code works just like mine do. It does't work for .swf data returned (were written to response) by MediaHandler.

Comment: Thanks for link, but it agai doesn't work with httpHandler :(

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!

In the handler, I was setting Response Header's parameters the same values as they were in the case with directly referring to an existing file.

Now, I just removed all this values, and it works!
I still can't understand why, but it works :)

Comment: can you please share the full code?
i have running with same problem, i also want swf source from http handler, please share both side code and client side for this handler