# display swf files on a page with httpHandler

Tags: asp.net, flash, handler, swfobject

I want to display swf file on page with http handler. AS want to make handler for swf src.
my code look like:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="520" height="440">
<param name="src" value="handler/myhandler.ashx" />
<param name="AutoSize" value="true">
<param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
<param name="AutoStart" value="true">
<param name="StretchToFit" value="true">
```

and handler code for server side is:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
context.Response.Write("myflash.swf");
```

Similar question is at [Can't display .swf files on a page with httpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953236/cant-display-swf-files-on-a-page-with-httphnadler)
His solution is "Now, I just removed all this values, and it works! I still can't understand why, but it works"
I didn't get him..
Is any one help me out

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("filename={0}", "tmyflash.swf"));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile("myflash.swf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

and client side

```
<embed src="myhandler.ashx" >
```